# String to json conversion python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm currently working with slack outbound webhooks, so some parsing of data that comes in needs to be done.

I have looked at several answers regarding json parsing but I cant seem to be able to figure out whats wrong with what I'm doing.

Here is what I send to my website

`start:'{"target": "taget", "project_name": "test"}'`

After some parsing I have: (Doing `print (my_message)`)

`'{"target": "taget", "project_name": "test"}'` with `<class(str)>`

I then try to convert this into json by doing

```
my_message = json.loads(json.dumps(my_message))
```

But this returns a `<class(str)>`

Is it there a way to parse this string in a way that data can be accesed like a dict? Like such

`json_message['target']`

EDIT: By doing directly `my_message = json.loads(my_message)`, `JSONDecodeError` comes up

Comment: try `json.loads(my_message)` (assuming my_message is the string containing the JSON object).

Comment: `JSONDecodeError` comes up when trying that.

Comment: Then the content of `my_message` is probably invalid JSON. What does `print(my_message)` show?

Comment: `print(my_message)` yields `'{"target": "taget", "project_name": "test"}'`

Comment: Those single quotes at the beginning and end should not be there. If you explain where the data comes from and what you want to do with it, you might receive a helpful answer.

Comment: By removing the single quotes from the first message sent and doing `json.loads(my_message)` a valid json is returned. Thanks for the help!. Could you post as an answer so it can be accepted?